# How to make Jmeter use each login only once

Tags: jmeter

I am writing a JMeter webdriver test for 8 concurrent users.
In my test, I created a CSV Data Set Config with 10 logins.

I have noticed that JMeter is reusing the same login for at least 2 users.
This causes an issue where the 2 logins are trying to do the same task and one of them will fail waiting for specific elements to appear.

Is there a way to force JMeter to always use an unique login per user?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of your test and how you set up the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

If you set ["Sharing Mode"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) to `All Threads` - each thread will be reading new value on each iteration:

[image]

however if you will have more than 1 iteration:

- 1st user will read line # 9
- 2nd user will read line # 10
- 3rd user will read line #1

If you want to have "unique" data consider the following approaches:

1. Using [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function to read the data from file, this way you  will have control on when to proceed to the next line
2. Using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which ["READ"](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) endpoint has `KEEP=FALSE` parameter so once data is used it is removed so no other thread can use it.

Comment: Thanks. Using your comments about CSV Data Set Config, I think I solved my problem. Basically, I had 2 Thread Groups and 2 CSV Data Set Configs. It looks like both data set reads a line whenever a thread group is executed even if the thread group is not referencing the data set. This meant my data set hit EOF much quicker than expected. I fixed it by changing the Sharing mode to Current Thread Group.